# MQ mesage is not downloading sometime , Suggest any remote MQ monitor tool

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I wrote code to connect remote MQ and download the message but sometime some message is missing . I'm posting my code . Can anyone tell me what is the error in this code

```
using IBM.WMQ;

internal class MQReader
{
    private static MQQueueManager queueManager;
    private static MQMessage queueMessage;
    private static MQGetMessageOptions queueGetMessageOptions;
    private static MQQueue queue;
    static string strReturn = "";
    static string message = "";
    static string mqexception = "";
    static string connerror = "";
    static string QueueName;
    static string QueueManagerName;
    static string ChannelInfo;
    static string channelName;
    static string PortNumber;
    static string transportType;
    static string connectionName;
    static bool running;
    static bool conresult;
    static string checkconnexp;
    static bool connerrorflag;
    static bool checkconnresult;

    public static bool connectMQ()
    {
        bool flag;
        QueueManagerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueManager"];
        QueueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Queuename"];
        ChannelInfo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChannelInformation"];
        PortNumber = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"];
        char[] separator = { '/' };
        string[] ChannelParams;
        ChannelParams = ChannelInfo.Split(separator);
        channelName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Channel"];
        transportType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TransportType"];
        connectionName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionName"];

        try
        {
            queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName,
                channelName, connectionName);
            queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(QueueName,
                MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
            connerror = "Connected Successfully";
            flag = true;
        }
        catch (MQException connectionexp)
        {
            connerror = "Exception: " + connectionexp.Message;
            logFile(connerror);
            flag = false;
        }

        return flag;
    }

    private static void logFile(string errormsg)
    {
        string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logFilePath"];
        string fileName = path + "MQLog" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt";
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fileName, errormsg + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public static void getMessage()
    {
        conresult = connectMQ();
        running = true;

        while (running)
        {
            if (conresult == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    queueMessage = new MQMessage();
                    queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
                    queueGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
                    queueGetMessageOptions.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                    queueGetMessageOptions.WaitInterval = 60000;
                    queue.Get(queueMessage, queueGetMessageOptions);
                    message = queueMessage.ReadString(queueMessage.MessageLength);
                }
                catch (MQException exp)
                {
                    mqexception = exp.Message;
                    message = "Exception: " + mqexception;
                }

                if (message != "Exception: " + mqexception)
                {
                    string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xmlFilePath"];
                    string fileName = path + "MQMessage" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".xml";
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, message);         
                }
                else   
                {
                    logFile(message);
                    queueManager.Close();
                    queueManager.Disconnect();
                    conresult = false;
                }
            }

            if (conresult == false)
            {                   
                conresult = connectMQ();
            }
        }
    }

    public void InitializeConnections()
    {
        getMessage();
    }       

    public void StopIt()
    {
        queueManager.Disconnect();
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Sometimes message is not downloading or missing into local directory. All connection codes are credentials are coming from web.config.

**EDIT**
Please suggest any remote mq monitor tool which will log when message is sent into mq and when it's downloaded . Any power shell script or any tool anything will do fine .

Comment: 150 lines of code to 4 lines of question is not a good ratio. Have you checked the MQ logs?

Comment: Hello @stuartd I don't know the process of how to read MQ logs

Comment: [Logs in WebSphere MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455835/logs-in-websphere-mq) may help - _"When the message is put, you can request Confirmation on Delivery. When the message is consumed, a report message is delivered to the Reply-To Queue and Reply-To QMgr that were set in the original message"_

Comment: There really isn't a lot of information here. You've just posted your code and asked us what is wrong but haven't told us what debugging you've done yourself. You've not even posted what output your program is producing.

As other people have said you should start by looking at the error logs to see if MQ is posting any errors. Additionally please add more details to this question to help us to point out what is going wrong.

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in your application when message is "missing"? Also are you sure there messages in the queue when you try to get?

Comment: can anyone suggest me any tool to monitor remote mq activity like when message is put into mq and downloaded from remote mq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll be polite and only say 'Yuk' to that code.

First off, C# is an object oriented language so you should learn how to use try, catch & finally.

```
if (message != "Exception: " + mqexception)
```

What is that?  That is not how you do string comparison and why isn't that code in the try{} section?

```
string fileName = path + "MQMessage" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".xml";
```

Hummm.  You didn't lose your messages, you threw them away.  What happens if you get 2 or more messages during the same millisecond?

From the docs for Write​All​Text:

> Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes
>   the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

So, that means when you get 2 or more messages during the same millisecond the next one overwrites the previous one.

Comment: Hello @Roger . thank you for reply . I really appreciate it . it will improve my coding . thank you :) I got your point but any solution for this .. what should I do to solve this problem. any hints any links will be helpful

Comment: Here are 2 ideas: (1) Do not overwrite but append the new data to the file or (2) Create a method to check if the file already exists, if it does, add a counter to the file name and check again until the file is not found then use that file name. Also, why don't you put a message counter in your program and output when it is done. Hence, you should have the same number of output files as what the message counter states.

Comment: thank you Roger . I will try your way and post my new code

Comment: Roger I can not use counter at the time of message sending cause some other team is sending message . I am trying to append data to new file each and every time new  message is in MQ . let's see .

Comment: I said add a message counter in YOUR code not in the sending application.  Also, why aren't you logging the MsgId and CorrelId of each message along with the file name that the message was written to.  You should use application logging so that it is easy to determine where a problem is.